# Minimization of DFA- one state mark or no mark?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I want to know, what if the DFA is merged states. So if my DFA starts with q0 and then have (q0,q1) state it goes to with an 'a' for example. How do I do the table filling method.

I tried to rename the merged state, for example turning (q0,q1) to q4 for example. But then the issue is when I try to do the table filling. With the input in the Automaton, I get only one state, sometimes the final state. So do I mark it.

For example, I renamed (q0,q1) to q4. Now in the table, if I want to find out the marking for q0 and q4. With an 'a' I get q4,q4 for both of the state and with 'b' I get nothing from q0 and q2(final state) from q4. I know since q4,q4 does not exist I do not mark. But I only get one state, which happens to be the final state. Do I mark q0,q4 part of the table or do I leave that blank aswell

edit:

q0 --a-> q2(a to itself) --b-> q3(final)<--b--q4

so if i do the table filling method, Myhill Nerode Theorem, say i want to find out where q1, q4 goes with a, q1 goes to q2, q4 goes no where. then for b, q1 goes nowhere and q4 goes to q3(final state). can I mark the table if i only get one final state??

Comment: I guess you are talking about the construction of a minimal DFA from a DFA? Can you provide some definitions for context? How did you define the state pairs like $(q_0, q_1)$?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more context.  I am not sure what "what if the DFA is merged states" means.  What "table filling method" are you referring to?  Where did you see these, and what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: There are several algorithms to build minimal DFAs in the wild. Without a more precise description of the exact algorithm, and where you got stuck, little help is possible.

Comment: ok I edited, please look

Comment: Why are you renaming groups of states as new states, halfway through? Just keep sets, do the relabeling of sets as states when yo are done.